# Regular expression to match anything between two string except any word

Tags: c#, regex, pdftotext

I have a sentence where between the start and end point of the sentence it could include any special character or digit or letter but not a word.

To be more clear on my point I have illustrated below with an example:

I have a sentence like `"Today's Market value      0.5 percent"`

Now from above sentence in between "Market value" and "percent", I must not get any other word.

```
Statements allowed:
1) "Today's Market value*    0.5 percent"
2) "Today's Market value\1   0.5 percent"
3) "Today's Market value \1 0.5 percent"
4) "Today's Market value e   0.5 percent"
5) "Today's Market value 0.5 percent"

Statements not allowed:
1) "Today's market value is    0.5 percent"
2) "Today's market value  is 0.5 percent"

3) "Today's Market value is 0.5 percent"
```

And I am mainly interested in picking up the market value i.e "0.5" here.

Kindly suggest me a proper way to to build a regex to accomplish my above requirement.

Comment: Why is `value e 0.5 percent` allowed?

Comment: so you want any number written before percent ?

Comment: @Robin value 0.5 is allowed because that is my point of interest, I mean that's the value which I actually want to extract.

Comment: The following regex works for all your cases: `(?<=Market value)(\w?[\s\d\.*\\]+)+(?=percent)`

Comment: @aelor No, I want number written exactly between "Market value" and "percent" and the strict condition is it should not contain any other word between these two phrases.

Comment: Why don't you just `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` ?

Comment: @user2786794: yes, but why isn't `e` considered a word? What do you actually consider to be a word?

Comment: `/Today's Market value[\*\e\\1\.\d ]*percent/i` looks yuck.. but can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to extract the number of interest if the string is ok:

```
string[] strList = new[] {
    @"Today's Market value*    0.5 percent",
    @"Today's Market value\1   0.5 percent",
    @"Today's Market value \1 0.5 percent",
    @"Today's Market value e   0.5 percent",
    @"Today's Market value 0.5 percent",
    @"Today's market value is    0.5 percent",
    @"Today's market value  is 0.5 percent",
    @"Today's Market value is 0.5 percent"
};
foreach (string str in strList)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=Market value.*\s)(?<!Market value.*[a-zA-Z]{2}.*)\d+(\.\d+)?(?=\s.*percent)(?!.*[a-zA-Z]{2}.*percent)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    if (m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", m.Value, str);
}
```

Output:

```
0.5 : Today's Market value*    0.5 percent
0.5 : Today's Market value\1   0.5 percent
0.5 : Today's Market value \1 0.5 percent
0.5 : Today's Market value e   0.5 percent
0.5 : Today's Market value 0.5 percent
```

Basic idea: the number should be preceded by **Market value** text, *anything* and **whitespace**, but shouldn't be preceded by **Market value + 2 or more sequential letters anywhere** text. Also the number should be followed by **whitespace**, *anything* and **percent** text, but shouldn't be followed by **2 or more sequential letters anywhere + percent**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\bMarket value\b(?!\s+is\s)[\s\S]*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*percent\b
```

`(?!\s+is\s)` is negative lookahead, checking that there is no `is` after the `Market value`.

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yQ5oI6)